# How can I create one user that have complete access to MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

This is really bugging me. I intend to create one user that controls all access to my MongoDB and also use the same user for all my applications. I realize having separate users would be even more secure but I want to keep this simple.

Unfortunately, it does not seem so straightforward to give superuser access. So far I have given the admin user as:

```
db.addUser({user:"admin", pwd:"ppp", 
roles: ["clusterAdmin", "readWriteAnyDatabase", "dbAdminAnyDatabase", "userAdminAnyDatabase"] } )
```

But admin can still not be used to authenticate against another db than admin db itself. For example

`mongo raconteurdb -u admin -p
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9
Enter password: 
connecting to: raconteurdb
Tue Apr  1 10:10:57.109 Error: 18 { code: 18, ok: 0.0, errmsg: "auth fails" } at src/mongo/shell/db.js:228`

Do I need to set access for each DB separate? Will I lose that access when those DBs are dropped?

Answer (score 2):

RipperDoc,

You can use the admin users to authenticate for any database. If the appropriate privileges were setup for the user, you could have used following:

```
mongo raconteurdb -u admin -p --authenticationDatabase admin
```

This will authenticate "admin" user setup in the "admin" database and "raconteurdb" will be default db on the mongo-shell.

Comment: Thanks aks, that pointed me in the right direction, I can see now that pymongo's authenticate supports a similar source authentication database. Will test asap.

Comment: The problem is that MongoEngine drivers don't support using a source database for authentication, and it also seems to ignore the otherDBRoles field that can be set on the admin system.users db. So I guess there are no other options except creating separate users for each DB.